# Getting duplicates with NiFi HBase_1_1_2_ClientMapCacheService

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to remove duplicates from a flow I've developed, it can receive the same ${filename} multiple times.  I tried using HBase_1_1_2_ClientMapCacheService with DetectDuplicate (I am using NiFi v1.4), but found that it lets a few duplicates through.  If I use DistributedMapCache (ClientService and Server), I do not get any duplicates.  Why would I receive some duplicates with the HBase Cache?

As a test, I listed a directory (ListSFTP) with 20,000 files on all cluster nodes (4 nodes) and passed to DetectDuplicate (using the HBase Cache service).  It routed 20,020 to "non-duplicate", and interestingly the table actually has 20,000 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think this is due to a limitation in the operations that are offered by HBase.

The DetectDuplicate processor relies on an operation "getAndPutIfAbsent" which is expected to return the original value, and then set the new value if it wasn't there. For example, first time through it would return null and set the new value, indicating it wasn't a duplicate.

HBase doesn't natively support this operation, so the implementation of this method in the HBase map cache client does this:

```
V got = get(key, keySerializer, valueDeserializer);
boolean wasAbsent = putIfAbsent(key, value, keySerializer, valueSerializer);

if (! wasAbsent) return got;
      else return null;
```

So because it is two separate calls there is a possible race condition...

Imagine node 1 calls the first line and gets null, but then node 2 performs the get and the putIfAbsent, now when node 1 calls putIfAbsent it gets false because node 2 just populated the cache, so now node 1 returns the null value from the original get... both of these look like non-duplicates to DetectDuplicate.

In the DistributedMapCacheServer, it locks the entire cache per operation so it can provide an atomic getAndPutIfAbsent.